# How to permanently delete data on an android phone including images videos and etc..?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, data-recovery, delete

I have and android phone and I usually delete images and also delete them from trash . But I always can recover deleted items by using third party recovery apps like diskdigger and all deleted files can be recovered by doing this way .

I was wondering If there is a way to delete anything on my phone permanently which cant be recovered ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your phone it's rooted or if you know terminal but `rm` it is a badass delete command even in Linux it is really hard to get information from, deleted whit `rm` but not impossible if you want to don't have to factory reset your phone for delete something you can over write on it, like delete it whit

```
rm -rf myfolder/to/delete
```

okay and then over write the space left on the device like

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/some_file_name.txt bs=1024 MiB=space_left_on_megabites
```

this will create a file of the size of the space left on where you want to overwrite the sd or the internal storage you must be really carefully whit the `dd` command  "space_left_on_megabites" it is the amount of megabytes left on the device if you have 6 gb it must be MiB=6000 etc..

you will get the notification of running out of space on the device don't worry you would get it back

ones the `dd` command finish it will take some time it's writing whit zeros on all the space left, then you delete the /sdcard/some_file_name.txt whit `rm`

```
rm -rf /sdcard/some_file_name.txt
```

then you have wipe ones you available space if you what to make it harder you must repeat the process like 5 times and then it will be really really impossible to recover it! but whit one time does app you mention it wont be available to get it back