# How to delete file completely?

Tags: file-system, files, delete, cleanup

It's [not a duplicate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233439/how-to-shred-deleted-files-to-prevent-data-recovery), because this question isn't about shredding files that already deleted, it's about deleting them in the first place in a way that recovery software wouldn't find it.

I delete photos, but this software [FindMyPhoto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free) still recovers them. I think photos are really deleted, and those that restored are thumbnails, because when I restore them they doesn't look that sharp. I delete photos through the Gallery application. I tried to clean Gallery app cache, that doesn't help.

I tried to use firmware (preinstalled by manufacturer) that cleans Android of junk (like cache etc), but the application above still finds it. And I don't know how to completely remove the files. It's like I've got a device with undeletable files and starting really hate Android (it's really betrayal and annoying behavior).

So if you could recommend some application may be (preferably from a well known company or free software, like those  from F-Droid repository) I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @Firelord i think that is a follow-up question of this one https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231132

Comment: it is still a mystery to me, this app does not restore anything on my device (rooted, no encryption). if you delete a file via `rm` from terminal and clear gallery app data, the file is gone

Comment: @alecxs Yes, it'a a fllow-up of those question. I knew I'd better do not buy Chinese phone (Xiaomi).

Comment: You could take a look at my [corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe). Though due to wear-leveling on flash storage, I always wonder if those apps even *can* work.

Comment: This question is still missing relevant information: 1. What files do you try to delete (where are they located, path, partition, ...). 2. How do you delete those files? Which command or app do you use to delete those files? 3. Have you made sure that the delete command was really executed? reboot the device and use `adb` to check if the files really have been deleted (and not just moved some sort of trash).

Comment: @Robert I think photos are really deleted, and those that restored are thumbnails, because when I restore them they doesn't look that sharp. I delete photos through the Gallery application. I tired to clean Gallery app cache, that doesn't help.

Comment: btw i really think it matters if you clear gallery **app data** (not just gallery cache). also try *'rm -r /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails'* (not sure if exist)

Comment: Thumbnails are separate files from the actual pictures on many phones. They are usually hidden from many apps because they are located in a directory (or subdirectory of one) that also contain a hidden file named .nomedia

Comment: @alecxs hard to find how to delete data, not cache. May be it's because I have MIUI. And there is no `/storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails` file or directory.

Comment: @svin83 I deleted `.nomedia` from `.../cache` of Gallery app, it did absolutely nothing. How about `.../uil-images/journal` file?

Comment: Deleting the .nomedia file in a directory will only un-hide media files in that directory and all subdirectories... That means those files (if any) will also show up in your gallery... It won't delete thumbnails... I never said it would...

Comment: @svin83 it seems they haven't appeared.

Comment: Well stop using the gallery to delete what the gallery tells you isn't there... Use a REAL file manager to delete images and thumbnails and then go clear the gallery app cache in Android settings->Apps->"Gallery app name"->Storage... Then use the "clear cache" button...

Answer (score 0):

MIUI Gallery creates thumbnails in

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.miui.gallery/files/gallery_disk_cache/full_size
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.miui.gallery/files/gallery_disk_cache/small_size
```

Some versions of MIUI Gallery do not even delete thumbnails when pictures are deleted.

Unlike for user apps MIUI does not provide the Clear Data button for system apps. The Clear Cache button does not wipe app data, therefore one need 3rd Party app to Clear Data (Link2SD can do it)

[image] [image]

Once you deleted files from

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android
```

such apps like [FindMyPhoto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free) and similar stop working, as they don't really undelete files.