# How do Android data recovery tools work without root?

Tags: data-recovery, root-access, recovery-mode

Sometimes I come across tools like [DroidKit](https://www.imobie.com/droidkit/) which promise to recover your data from Android phone without root. I do not understand, how they obtain raw binary access to internal storage over USB only. Or is it just a marketing trick when in reality they just mounting only external SD card to local computer and perform recovery on it?

Comment: Check the [user guide](https://www.imobie.com/guide/droidkit/deep-android-data-recovery.htm). It does root the device for performing something called Deep Scan. At least the software author is honest enough to mention this in the guide at least.

Comment: scam. it's impossible to root a device and recover files for various reasons

Comment: @Firelord, thanks for this reference! But what about quick scan this tool offer? Is there any Android API which lets do data recovery?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233452

Comment: @alecxs it might be a scam but with levels/grades. On Android versions, where as of now it is easy to get escalated privileges by using exploits, it might be possible to temporarily root the device (run the exploit and keep changes non-persistent). So it could be that this software fails to root let's say Android 12 or 13 but it could be able to do so on an Android 5 or 6 or 7 device. // Or it might just be a complete scam like you said.

Comment: I recommend to check the trust rating of such sites like [iMobie](https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/imobie.com) iMyFone wondershare Dr.Fone and all these wonderful magic products