# Recovering data from "Recently deleted" folder (SD card) in Huawei P20 after removal

Tags: recovery-mode, sd-card, huawei-p20

I sent some files from my SD card to the "Recently deleted" folder and then removed the card.

May I be able to recover these files if I insert back the SD?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try this [app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231132/is-there-alternative-to-the-shred-utility-for-android?r=SearchResults#comment305359_231132) from comments

Comment: i have better experience reconstructing pictures with [ZAR](https://www.z-a-recovery.com)/[Klennet Carver](https://www.klennet.com/carver) especially on read errors caused by emmc wear-out. of course this method does not apply to encrypted sd card ([adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info))

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to recover data from an SD card would be by connecting it to a PC.  I recommend an open source, cross-platform tool called 'PhotoRec'

```
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)
```

The reason is that files can be a little broken when they're recovered from being deleted, so having a tool that understands file structures can be helpful.  The name 'PhotoRec' is a little misleading, since it actually recovers hundreds of different file types

```
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec)
```

There's a good tutorial here since the UI is quite simplistic:

```
https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/photorec-recover-photos-memory-card/
```