# Recover deleted photos on LG Q6 (rooting)

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, lg

I've downloaded 'Disk Drill' to search for the photos and it informed me that I have to root the device for 'Disk Drill' to work. I've tried both with Kingoroot and Kingroot to root the device, both failed.

How to root an LG Q6? Or, if there is another way that doesn't require rooting, how can I search for the deleted photos?

Comment: Regarding Kingoroot and Kingroot: [Why are the rooting apps not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/44325), so looks like there's only the traditional hard-root method left (unlock the bootloader, flash custom recovery, flash `su` binary). However, looks like [the bootloader doesn't seem unlockable](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lg-q6-lg-m700a-unlock-bootloader.3691924/). Last is [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217116/44325) if it's anything possible. (I can't comment on file recovery since I've never tried it)

Comment: unlocking bootloader will perform factory reset and wipe encryption keys. you can't recover any data afterwards. your only chance is flashing magisk patched boot.img on locked bootloader. this requires firehose programmer and deep flash cable (some devices must disassembled to find test point)

Comment: even then chances to recover deleted files are nearly zero. try to search hidden *.trashcan* instead (see app in [comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231132/is-there-alternative-to-the-shred-utility-for-android#comment305359_231132))

Comment: https://twitter.com/alephsecurity/status/955378924124557313